# Close all NERDtree instances on VIM exit

Tags: vim, nerdtree

If you have any NERDTree instances open when you quit VIM then when you open your session again you get a number of errors:

```
Error detected while processing BufLeave Autocommands for "NERD_tree_*":
E121: Undefined variable: b:NERDTree
Error detected while processing WinLeave Autocommands for "NERD_tree_*":

Error detected while processing BufLeave Autocommands for "NERD_tree_*":
E121: Undefined variable: b:NERDTree
Error detected while processing WinLeave Autocommands for "NERD_tree_*":
```

I am trying to execute `:tabdo NERDTreeClose` automatically when vim exits (e.g. with qa or wqa or qa! etc)

I am adding:

`autocmd VimLeave * tabdo NERDTreeClose<CR>` or
`autocmd VimLeave * :tabdo NERDTreeClose<CR>`

with or without `<CR>` at the end but I can't make it work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have previously encountered the exact same issue with the combination of
creating (and reentering) `[neo]Vim`-sessions and multiple `NERDTree`-instances.

My solution, which might not be the precise answer that you are looking for
due to the reason that will be explained later, was to **first** close all `NERDTree`
instances **before** creating or updating the `[neo]Vim`-Session for later usage.
What you have been trying so far with the `tabdo` is thus a few "stages" too
late, as the triggering event for auto-command is `VimLeave`.

My primary suggestion (also my personal resort) is to create a quick
key-bind that performs the two procedures I stated above combined with a quick
save-all in serial:

```
cnoremap W tabdo NERDTreeClose <bar> wa <bar> mksession! ~/.vim/My_Session.vim
```

which can be comfortably remembered as the bigger brother of the default `w` in
commandline-mode for saving (a single buffer).

The one caveat of this method is that all instances of `NERDTree` will be closed
when reentering the session saved from above. This, however, can be somewhat
remedied by calling `NERDTreeToggle` with `VimEnter` as the triggering event for
`autocmd`.

If you insist on utilising `autocmd` for this, I would suggest putting the two
procedures enlisted above into a function and use `autocmd` to call that
function (with the `[neo]Vim` command: call) upon `VimLeave` just like you have
tried before, of course under the assumption that you feel compelled to save the session during every exit. I personally do not endorse this, as instances were abundant where
I would quickly fire up `[neo]Vim` for a quick note of something inconsequential
and swiftly exit, which certainly does not require that the session be saved.

As a sidenote: the syntax of autocmd:

```
:au[tocmd] [group] {event} {pat} [++once] [++nested] {cmd}
```

thus, substitute `cmd` with a command directly, i.e., the prefixing colon as you
have tried in your original post is a malpractice.